# Remove substring from absolute path windows script

Tags: windows, batch, script

I am new to windows scripts and I have the absolute path like- `/bin/debug/test/abc.xyz.dll` and I want to remove the file name and get only path like output: `/bin/debug/test/`.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extended features of a `FOR` loop for this - even if it will not "loop":

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
set "arg=%~1"
for /f %%A in ('echo %arg%') do echo %%~pA
```

where you call this script with the full filename, possibly quoted to protect spaces within.

**edit:**
My original code used `echo %%~nxA` which clearly was wrong, sorry. It isolates the filename from the path, and returns the filename. The above code now returns the path only (without the drive letter).

**edit2:**
I'm grateful to @Karan for pointing out that this can be abbreviated to

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
echo %~p1
```

because the extended variable expansion syntax is available not only in `FOR` loops but with **argument expansion** as well (see CALL /?).

Comment: -1 This does not show just the path without the filename as desired. Test with the input string that's provided and ensure the output string matches what has been specified in the question (possibly with forward slashes too).

Comment: @Karan: oops, you're 100% right. My code returned the filename only, and cut off the path. Corrected now for just the opposite. Sometimes can't see the tree for the forest...

Comment: Ok, reversed my vote but this will still convert forward slashes to backslashes. I don't know why the OP is using the former in Windows though, so unless forward slash support is stated as a requirement this should suffice. However the code still seems unnecessarily bloated. Can you tell me what all that does that a simple `@echo %~p1` won't accomplish? Why are `setlocal` and an extra variable and a `for` even required?

Comment: Yes, I've not yet seen a `/bin/...` folder on my Win PC. The `for` loop is mandatory although it doesn't loop at all. The modifiers for shell variable expansion (~p, ~nx etc.) are extensions to the `for` syntax not for the cmd shell. See `FOR /?` for reference. `setlocal EnableExtensions` is necessary as without the expansion syntax is disabled. Again, `FOR /?`.

Comment: I'm not looking to be pointed towards the documentation, which I know quite well. I think you completely missed my point. Run a single line batch file containing only `@echo %~p1` with the argument `/bin/debug/test/abc.xyz.dll`. Compare output with your code that uses `setlocal` and an extra variable and a `for`. Tell me how they are different. Why use extra code and memory when it can apparently be done with one simple line? Unless you can tell me how my code is worse?

Comment: Your example produces the same correct output only because - the cmd extensions are enabled on your PC by default, and - because the extended substitution syntax works in FOR loops and with commandline arguments (and only there! not with regular shell variables). For the general case you need the `setlocal` command to ensure the extensions are enabled. So you can use your code as well. I doubt that the FOR loop syntax is a noticable waste though.

Comment: Yes, cmd extensions are always enabled by default so hardly a problem for anyone I'd say. It takes special effort (`cmd /E:off`) to disable them in fact. Using an extra variable (arg) is pointless IMO. Anyway, won't debate it any more.